# Should I use an array or an object for REST API collections?

Tags: rest, collections, model

My API contains a `Book` entity which represents a collection of several possible `BookContent` depending on the language. A `BookContent` is another entity with the attributes `Title` and `Content`, which both depend on the `Language`.

Should a `Book` look like:

1)

```
[
  {
     "language": "English",
     "title": "First title",
     "content": "First content"
  },
  {
     "language": "French",
     "title": "Premier titre",
     "content": "Premier contenu"
  }
]
```

or like:

2)

```
{
  "English": {
     "title": "First title",
     "content": "First content"
  },
  "French": {
     "title": "Premier titre",
     "content": "Premier contenu"
  }
}
```

The option 1):

- produces "self-contained" elements, i.e. each object contains all the information.
- The `language` attribute can contain any Unicode character (whereas as a key it cannot).
- is the only available option if the content depends on multiple criteria, i.e. language and year.
- creates a clearer separation between the two entities. For example, it makes it easier to replace each element by its ID, if we were to decide not to embed the `BookContent` entity anymore but only return the `BookContent` ID.
- is probably more familiar to developers using my API, since I believe it is more common to find this kind of structure in other REST APIs.

The option 2):

- produces smaller elements.
- makes it faster to look for the elements according to the language without traversing through the whole collection.

This is a general question to know which one looks more like a "best practice", with no assumption on how the clients are querying/using the REST API, nor how much performance matters as opposed to flexibility, etc.

Which option is generally more often a "best practice"?

Comment: This really depends on your need.

Comment: How would you list more than one English book in your second sample?

Comment: You are right the example was unclear, I changed the example case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state in your question that:

> This is a general question to know which one looks more like a "best practice", with no assumption on how the clients are querying/using the REST API.

You are writing a REST service that is designed to help clients get information out - if that wasn't your aim, there'd be no point writing it. Because of this, the most important question you need to answer is "what information do clients want?". The answer to *that* will dictate the structure of your data, not "which one looks better?" - we're not your service's end users.

*Personally*, I'd opt for the first, simply because it would seem wrong to have an array called `books.English` in my object, it also allows for languages with characters outside of A-Z, and caters for books where the language is not known (or mixed). If simplicity of the individual book is key (and the list of languages is well-defined and finite), then consider:

```
[
    {
        "language": "English",
        "books": [{
            "title": "First title",
            "content": "First content"
        }]
    },
    {
        "language": "French",
        "books": [{
            "title": "Premier titre",
            "content": "Premier contenu"
        }]
    }
]
```

In essence, however, there's no single best practise for the data structures you're building other than "make them useful".

Comment: Sorry I just fixed the model, using different names